# Python transpose/swap dataframe column and row in csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, pivot, transpose

I would like transpose/swap all the columns into the row of my csv files.

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np

path =r'/Users/orochimaru/Documents/ParisSportif/foo/merge.csv'
stockstats_data = pd.DataFrame.transpose(path)
list_ = []

for file_ in path:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_)
    stockstats_data = pd.concat((df, stockstats_data), axis=1)

    stockstats_data.to_csv('merget.csv', index=False)
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions please? Thanks a lot guys !

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path =r'/Users/orochimaru/Documents/ParisSportif/foo/*.csv'
files = glob.glob(path)

frame = []
for file in files:
    frame.append(pd.read_csv(file))

df = pd.concat(frame)
df.T.to_csv('merget.csv', index=False)
```